# Statsmodels VECM - Predicting out-of-sample

Tags: python, vector-error-correction-model, statsmodels

After fitting a VECM model, I would like to study its out-of-sample behavior but haven't been able to find a way to do it.

More precisely, given `X_train` and `X_test`, I computed

```
from statsmodels.tsa.vector_ar.vecm import VECM
model = VECM(endog = X_train, k_ar_diff = 1, coint_rank = 2, deterministic = 'co')
res = model.fit()
X_pred = res.predict(X_test)
```

However, predict does not seem to be built for this. Is there any way around this?

Comment: This might be too software specific to be on topic.

Answer (score 0):

```
from statsmodels.tsa.vector_ar.vecm import VECM
model = VECM(endog = X_train, k_ar_diff = 1, coint_rank = 2, deterministic = 'co')
res = model.fit()
X_pred = res.predict(steps=10)
```

e.g. set `steps=10` if your want predict 10 periods